# Meteor google map display markers depending on checkbox filter

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor

I have a map that currently displays all markers. I would like to update the markers on the map when a checkbox is clicked.

To load the markers I do

```
Caves.find({$or: [{ backmount: {$exists: false}},{backmount: true}]}).observe({
```

And if the checkbox is clicked it should change the filter to

```
Caves.find({ backmount: false}).observe({
```

I am not sure how to put that into my code.

This is the code to load the markers

```
Template.map.onCreated(function() {
  GoogleMaps.loadUtilityLibrary('js/geolocationmarker-compiled.js');
  GoogleMaps.loadUtilityLibrary('js/infobox.js');

  var markers = {};

  GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {
    var latLng = currentPosition();

    Tracker.autorun(function() {
      map.instance.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latLng.lat, latLng.lng));
      var GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker(map.instance);

    });

    Caves.find({$or: [{ backmount: {$exists: false}},{backmount: true}]}).observe({
      added: function(doc) {
        var infobox = new InfoBox({
          content: $("#infobox")[0],
          disableAutoPan: false,
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140,0),
          zIndex: null,
          infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1,1),
          boxStyle: {
            background: "url('images/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
            opacity: 0.75,
            width: "280px"
          }
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          draggable: false,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(doc.location.coordinates.latitude,doc.location.coordinates.longitude),
          id: doc._id,
          map: map.instance
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infobox.open(map.instance, this);
        });

        markers[doc._id] = marker;
      },
      changed: function(newDoc, oldDoc) {
        markers[newDoc._id].setPosition({ lat: newDoc.lat, lng: newDoc.lng});
      },
      removed: function(oldDoc) {
        markers[oldDoc._id].setMap(null);

        google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(markers[oldDoc._id]);

        delete markers[oldDoc._id];
      }
    });

  });
});
```

And I have a template with the checkbox (#sidemountOnly)

```
<template name="mapFilters">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="filemanager-options">
        <li>
          <div class="ckbox ckbox-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="sidemountOnly" value="1">
            <label for="sidemountOnly">Sidemount Only</label>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question. I used a session variable where I change the subsription. Some of the related code:

**Create an event:**

```
Template.mapFilters.events({
  "change #sidemountOnly": function(event) {
    Session.set("sidemountOnly",event.target.checked);
  }
})
```

Pass to subscription inside autorun

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
      getBox();
      Meteor.subscribe("primaryCoordinates", Session.get('box'), Session.get('sidemountOnly'));


      var GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker(map.instance);

    });
```

Create filter in publish on the server side

```
Meteor.publish('primaryCoordinates', function(box,sidemountOnly) {
  var filter = {};

  if(sidemountOnly) {
    filter = {backmount: false};
  } else {
    filter = {$or: [{ backmount: {$exists: false}},{backmount: true}]};
  }

  var find = { $and: [{
    location: {
      $geoWithin: {
        $box: box
      }
    }},filter]
  };

  return Caves.find(find);
});
```